# How to combine outputs of multiple tasks performed using Matlab SGE?

Tags: matlab, batch-file

I have the following batch file launching some m-files (`main.m` and `f.m` which are scripts) 4 times (4 tasks).

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=2G
#$ -l tmem=2G
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y

#Run 4 tasks where each task has a different $SGE_TASK_ID ranging from 1 to 4
#$ -t 1-4

#$ -N example


#Output the Task ID
echo "Task ID is $SGE_TASK_ID"

cat main.m f.m | matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash
```

At the end I obtain 4 outputs that are `example.o[...].1,example.o[...].2, example.o[...].3, example.o[...].4`. Each of them looks like

```
...
Task ID is ...

                        < M A T L A B (R) >
                                ...
>> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> 
output =

    4.0234   -3.4763
```

How can I combine these `4` outputs in a matrix `4x2` and save it?

Comment: Why don't you save the output from inside of your `f.m` file rather than relying on a log file? You're losing a ton of precision this way. Also consider accepting the answer on your other question since it's apparently working for you

Comment: I accepted it. How can I save it including the SGE_TASK_ID index in the name?

Comment: Sorry it looks like SO has some bad caching right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the relevant output from *within* `f.m` using MATLAB's save or something similar.

If you use the `-r` flag to call `main` and `f` from the command line you can add a variable which will contain the task ID and you can then access that from within `f.m`

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main; ID = $SGE_TASK_ID; f; exit"
```

Then within `f.m`

```
% You theoretically generate some numeric result
result = rand(1, 2);

filename = sprintf('Result.%d.mat', ID);
save(filename, 'result')
```

This will  save `Result.0.mat`, `Result.1.mat` etc.

Alternately, you could modify `f.m` such that it loads the data from the file, appends to it, and re-saves it every time

```
result = rand(1,2);

filename = 'Results.mat';

% If this is the first task, then create a new file, otherwise append to the old
if ID == 1
    data = result;
else
    tmp = load(filename, '-mat');
    data = tmp.data;
    data(ID,:) = result;
end

save(filename, 'data')
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you think the first option may be faster?

Comment: @user3285148 They are probably about the same performance-wise. It's more a matter of whether you want one file containing the data or many